# can't play video using a tag

Tags: android

i have a problem.in path destination.if video file name is fourtain.
and then

```
String uriPath = "android.resource://" + getPackageame()+"/"+R.raw.fourtain;
Uri uri = Uri.parse(UriPath);
```

but use a tag,how can i set path destination?below code is that i tried,but dont work(can't play video)

In activity_main.xml

```
android:id="@+id/v1"
android:tag="fourtain"
```

In MainActivity.java

```
int id = v.getId();
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(id);
String tag = (String)layout.getTag();
Resource res = getResources();

int id_1 = res.getIdentifier(tag, "raw", getPackageName());
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageame()+"/"+id_1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This..

```
VideoView view = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video_file; view.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
view.start();
```